# JSON.NET object array deserialization to known type class

Tags: asp.net-web-api, json.net, asp.net-web-api2

I have a class which is already being used in my projects with xml serializing. now i am using Web API which uses JSON.NET serializer to serialize and deserialize objects.

```
[Serializable]
public class MyClass
{
    private object[] itemsField;


    /// <remarks/>
    [System.Xml.Serialization.XmlElementAttribute("MyClass1", typeof(MyClass1))]
    [System.Xml.Serialization.XmlElementAttribute("MyClass2", typeof(MyClass2))]
    public object[] Items
    {
        get
        {
            return this.itemsField;
        }
        set
        {
            this.itemsField = value;
        }
    }

}

[Serializable]
public class MyClass1
{
    //some properties
}

[Serializable]
public class MyClass2
{
    // some properties
}
```

I am not getting MyClass1 in object array of MyClass's Items. Insteed it is giving me some JObject in Items.

Comment: Show the format of the json and the deserialization code!

Answer (score 0):

If I understand what you want to do, I think you can do it with a custom JsonConverter. But you will first need to restrict the type of Items in some way. For example you can define an interface IItems. Maybe it declares no methods, but what you do with it is apply the `[JsonConverter(typeof(MyJsonConverter))]` attribute to IItems. Then it will get invoked any time a member of Items is serialized or deserialized. This takes a bit of work, but it's the only way I've figured out how to do polymorphism in JSON.net.

Uh, there is built-in polymorphism support in JSON.net, but it requires special "type" keys to exist in the JSON, which your pre-existing format probably doesn't have.